# Error using wmake in project directory

Tags: linux, terminal, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

When using command "wmake" in directory "/home/USER/myProject" within the terminal I get the error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory
make: *** [/multiphaseEulerFoamNEW] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `wclean` before `wmake` .

greetings 
streight